# Is .NET Core 3.1.1 as Long Term Support (LTS) Version?

Tags: c#, .net-core

.NET Core 3.0 was not a long term support release.
.NET Core 3.1 is a long term support release.

Is .NET Core 3.1.1 a long term support release?

I want the security benefits, of 3.1.1, but not at the expense of a very short support cycle.

Comment: If you are asking whether Microsoft intends to support 3.1.1 after 3.1.2 (for example) is released, I think the answer is probably "no". 3.1.2 (when it is released) will be a bugfix or security update to 3.1.1. Why would Microsoft (or any other vendor) continue to support something that they found high priority issues in and then fixed those issues by releasing an update? How would they support "3.1.1" and fix any security issues that come other than by releasing an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, see here:

[image]
[.NET Core Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)

Answer (score 1):

**.NET Core 3.1.1** is not a LTS version, **.NET Core 3.1** is.

This is how version **3.1** is supported, by releasing new patch-versions of it.

It's impractical to provide long-term support on patch releases, since they are used precisely to provide long-term support.

**.NET Core 3.1** will continue to be updated (to **3.1.2**, **3.1.3**, etc.) until **December 3, 2022** ([source](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#lifecycle)).